# Backlight recognition of car using tflite and open cv

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to detect the traffic light and backlight of a car using tensor flow lite for implementation on raspberry pi 3B module. I am using coco_ssd_mobilenet sample model for detection.

I have succeeded in recognizing the traffic light and recognize the state of it's color and display a message if the signal is red.

Now I'm having trouble in recognizing the backlight of car. I use the bounding boxes of the detected object car as the region of interest. I define a mask of red color and try to get contours which are of red color (back light of car) and draw a bounding box using open CV. But these boxes seem to be out of place on the detection video which is shown in the image where as they should be on the backlight of car

It would be of great help if someone would tell me what is going wrong.
Thank you.

I have attached the complete code here

```py
    # Import packages
    import os
    import argparse
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import sys
    import importlib.util
    
    
    # Function to detect red and yellow color to stop the car when it detects these colors
    def detect_red_and_yellow(img, Threshold=0.01):
        """
        detect red and yellow
        :param img:
        :param Threshold:
        :return:
        """
    
        desired_dim = (30, 90)  # width, height
        img = cv2.resize(np.array(img), desired_dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    
        # lower mask (0-10)
        lower_red = np.array([0, 70, 50])
        upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])
        mask0 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    
        # upper mask (170-180)
        lower_red1 = np.array([170, 70, 50])
        upper_red1 = np.array([180, 255, 255])
        mask1 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red1, upper_red1)
    
        # defining the Range of yellow color
        lower_yellow = np.array([21, 39, 64])
        upper_yellow = np.array([40, 255, 255])
        mask2 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)
    
        # red pixels' mask
        mask = mask0 + mask1 + mask2
    
        # Compare the percentage of red values
        rate = np.count_nonzero(mask) / (desired_dim[0] * desired_dim[1])
    
        if rate > Threshold:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    
    # Function to detect Traffic light objects and crop this part of the image to recognize color inside the object. We will create a stop flag,which we will use to take the actions based on recognized color of the traffic light.
    def read_traffic_lights_object(image_np, boxes, scores, classes, max_boxes_to_draw=20, min_score_thresh=0.5,
                                   traffic_light_label=9):
        im_width, im_height, _ = image_np.shape
        #image = np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
        #    (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
        stop_flag = False
        for i in range(min(max_boxes_to_draw, boxes.shape[0])):
            if scores[i] > min_score_thresh and int(classes[i]) == traffic_light_label:
                ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = tuple(boxes[i].tolist())
                (left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width,
                                              ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)
                
                image = Image.fromarray(image_np)
                
                crop_img = image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    
                if detect_red_and_yellow(crop_img):
                    stop_flag = True
    
        return stop_flag
    
    # Function to detect the backlight of car and draw a bounding box to it.    
    def backlight(image_np, boxes, scores, classes, max_boxes_to_draw=20, min_score_thresh=0.5,
                                   car_label=2):
        im_height, im_width, _ = image_np.shape
        
        for i in range(min(max_boxes_to_draw, boxes.shape[0])):
            if scores[i] > min_score_thresh and int(classes[i]) == car_label:
                ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = tuple(boxes[i].tolist())
                (left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width,
                                              ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)
                
                image = Image.fromarray(image_np)
                
                crop_img = image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
                crop_img_arr = np.array(crop_img)
                # Convert RGB to HSV
                hsv = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img_arr, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
                
                # define range of red color in HSV
                # lower mask (0-10)
                lower_red = np.array([0, 70, 50])
                upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])
                mask0 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
                
                # upper mask (170-180)
                lower_red1 = np.array([170, 70, 50])
                upper_red1= np.array([180, 255, 255])
                mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red1, upper_red1)
        
                # Threshold the HSV image to get only red colors
                mask = mask0 + mask1
                (contours, _ ) = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(),
                                  cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                  cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
                
                if len(contours) >0:
                    red_area = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
                    (xg,yg,wg,hg) = cv2.boundingRect(red_area)
                    a = xg + left
                    b = yg + top
                    c = a + wg
                    d = b + hg
                    cv2.rectangle(image_np,(a,b),(c,d),(0,0,255),2)
        return contours 
    
    # Define and parse input arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--modeldir', help='Folder the .tflite file is located in',
                        required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--graph', help='Name of the .tflite file, if different than detect.tflite',
                        default='detect.tflite')
    parser.add_argument('--labels', help='Name of the labelmap file, if different than labelmap.txt',
                        default='labelmap.txt')
    parser.add_argument('--threshold', help='Minimum confidence threshold for displaying detected objects',
                        default=0.5)
    parser.add_argument('--video', help='Name of the video file',
                        default='test.mp4')
    parser.add_argument('--edgetpu', help='Use Coral Edge TPU Accelerator to speed up detection',
                        action='store_true')
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    MODEL_NAME = args.modeldir
    GRAPH_NAME = args.graph
    LABELMAP_NAME = args.labels
    VIDEO_NAME = args.video
    min_conf_threshold = float(args.threshold)
    use_TPU = args.edgetpu
    
    # Import TensorFlow libraries
    # If tflite_runtime is installed, import interpreter from tflite_runtime, else import from regular tensorflow
    # If using Coral Edge TPU, import the load_delegate library
    pkg = importlib.util.find_spec('tflite_runtime')
    if pkg:
        from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter
        if use_TPU:
            from tflite_runtime.interpreter import load_delegate
    else:
        from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import Interpreter
        if use_TPU:
            from tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter import load_delegate
    
    # If using Edge TPU, assign filename for Edge TPU model
    if use_TPU:
        # If user has specified the name of the .tflite file, use that name, otherwise use default 'edgetpu.tflite'
        if (GRAPH_NAME == 'detect.tflite'):
            GRAPH_NAME = 'edgetpu.tflite'   
    
    # Get path to current working directory
    CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()
    
    # Path to video file
    VIDEO_PATH = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,VIDEO_NAME)
    
    # Path to .tflite file, which contains the model that is used for object detection
    PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,GRAPH_NAME)
    
    # Path to label map file
    PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,LABELMAP_NAME)
    
    # Load the label map
    with open(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'r') as f:
        labels = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    
    # Have to do a weird fix for label map if using the COCO "starter model" from
    # https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview
    # First label is '???', which has to be removed.
    if labels[0] == '???':
        del(labels[0])
    
    # Load the Tensorflow Lite model.
    # If using Edge TPU, use special load_delegate argument
    if use_TPU:
        interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT,
                                  experimental_delegates=[load_delegate('libedgetpu.so.1.0')])
        print(PATH_TO_CKPT)
    else:
        interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT)
    
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
    
    # Get model details
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
    height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]
    width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]
    
    floating_model = (input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32)
    
    input_mean = 127.5
    input_std = 127.5
    
    # Open video file
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_PATH)
    imW = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    imH = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    
    while(video.isOpened()):
    
        # Acquire frame and resize to expected shape [1xHxWx3]
        ret, frame = video.read()
        if not ret:
          print('Reached the end of the video!')
          break
        frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame_rgb, (width, height))
        input_data = np.expand_dims(frame_resized, axis=0)
    
        # Normalize pixel values if using a floating model (i.e. if model is non-quantized)
        if floating_model:
            input_data = (np.float32(input_data) - input_mean) / input_std
    
        # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
        interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'],input_data)
        interpreter.invoke()
    
        # Retrieve detection results
        boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])[0] # Bounding box coordinates of detected objects
        classes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0] # Class index of detected objects
        scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[2]['index'])[0] # Confidence of detected objects
        #num = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[3]['index'])[0]  # Total number of detected objects (inaccurate and not needed)
        class_id = [2,9]
        
        #traffic_color_detection
        stop_flag = read_traffic_lights_object(frame, boxes, scores, int(classes))
        if stop_flag:
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Stop', (25, 25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        else:
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Go', (25, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 255), 2)
            
        backlight(frame, boxes, scores, classes)
        
        # Loop over all detections and draw detection box if confidence is above minimum threshold
        for i in range(len(scores)):
            if ((int(classes[i] == class_id[0] and scores[i] > 0.5) or (int(classes[i] == class_id[1] and scores[i] > 0.5)):
    
                # Get bounding box coordinates and draw box
                # Interpreter can return coordinates that are outside of image dimensions, need to force them to be within image using max() and min()
                ymin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][0] * imH)))
                xmin = int(max(1,(boxes[i][1] * imW)))
                ymax = int(min(imH,(boxes[i][2] * imH)))
                xmax = int(min(imW,(boxes[i][3] * imW)))
                
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin,ymin), (xmax,ymax), (10, 255, 0), 4)
    
                # Draw label
                object_name = labels[int(classes[i])] # Look up object name from "labels" array using class index
                label = '%s: %d%%' % (object_name, int(scores[i]*100)) # Example: 'person: 72%'
                labelSize, baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, 2) # Get font size
                label_ymin = max(ymin, labelSize[1] + 10) # Make sure not to draw label too close to top of window
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, label_ymin-labelSize[1]-10), (xmin+labelSize[0], label_ymin+baseLine-10), (255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED) # Draw white box to put label text in
                cv2.putText(frame, label, (xmin, label_ymin-7), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 0), 2) # Draw label text
    
        # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
        cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)
    
        # Press 'q' to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
    
    # Clean up
    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Link to output image frame of the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMpZH.jpg)

Comment: can you also show (possibly through an image) of what is seen and what is expected?

Comment: @learner I have added the complete code and the output image frame of a video that I'm getting where as the red detection boxes should be on the backlight of car.